# Using Spring boot security with dataSource is not working as I want

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have kept security before going to `/admin/admin` page . When I try to access the url then it terminates me towards the login page and after login I must be able to access the admin page. But my problem is if I use any username or password then it will be logged in i.e it is not checking the one which are in database. 
SecurityConfiguration.java

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { 


@Autowired 
private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Override 
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
    .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder()); 
} 


@Override 
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable();
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/admin").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll() 
            .and() 
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login"); 
} 

private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() { 
    return new PasswordEncoder() { 
        @Override 
        public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return charSequence.toString();
        } 

        @Override 
        public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
            return true; 
        } 
    }; 
} 
}
```

CustomUserDetails.java

I was doing this using a tutorials on youtube and in the `return getRoles() 
            .stream() 
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole())) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());`  is also showing error I got confused where did the `getRoles()` method came from, its not from the entity class.

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails { 

public CustomUserDetails(final User users) {
    super(users);
} 

@Override 
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    return getRoles() 
            .stream() 
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole())) 
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //return null;
} 
public List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role) {

    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    if (role == "ADMIN") {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    } else if (role == "USER") {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    return authList;
    }
    //I have skipped other method
```

login.html

```
<form th:action="@{/view/login}" method="post">
     <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label>
</div>
     <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> 
</label></div>
     <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>    </div>
 </form>
```

Controller

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping({"view", ""})
 public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
 @GetMapping(value = "/home")
 public String homePage(){
    return "home";
}
@GetMapping(value = "/onlineOrder")
public String onlineOrder(){
    return "onlineOrder";
}
@GetMapping(value="/login")
public String loginPage(){
    return "login";
}
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public String successLogin(){
    return "admin";
}
}
```

Comment: Remove your password encoder it is actually pretty useless as it doesn't actually check if the passwords are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Your encoder returns `true' for all passwords

```
return new PasswordEncoder() { 
    @Override 
    public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
        return charSequence.toString();
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
        return true; //<------------------------------------
    } 
};
```

So every password you enter is valid so user is logged in

Comment: Well I Changed it to false also didn't help. I think it will return true if the password matches but don't know exactly
How can I improve that ?

Comment: You CustomUserDetails should provide user with password then the encoder compares password entered by user with password provided from the CustomUserDetails